# Laravel migrate:refresh Doesn't Work After Composer Update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations, artisan-migrate

The command in the title return error message below:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::create(), 1 passed in
>   C:\xampp7\htdocs\assurance-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
>   on line 221 and exactly 2 expected

I installed the framework with the commands:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel assurance-web
version 5.7
```

Then executed:

```
php artisan make:migration create_banks_table --create=banks
```

I was able to run `php artisan migrate` with no errors. However, then when I run `php artisan migrate:refresh` I get the error above.

This is "2018_12_04_033726_create_table_banks.php":

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBanksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('banks', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('bank_name');
            $table->string('bank_code');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('banks');
    }
}
```

Comment: This shows a specific error before running any migration. If you just use `php artisan config:cache` or any other artisan command, you'll still get this error. It's not related with `migrate`. It just says fix that error first.

Comment: This also might not be in that file.

Comment: Look at your error log file in `storage/logs` folder, you'll find the source.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your migration table is compromised. 
You can use:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

instead of "php artisan migrate:refresh" and the migration will see that it will work.

The "php artisan migrate:fresh" command physically deletes all tables instead of rolling back.